# I'm not sure, but might have something stuck in my ear

Tags: ear

Since Sunday, My right ear feels like something is lodged in it, but only seems to be in bed. What can I do to confirm it, and what can I actually do?

*Note- I'm Only 16, And I've already checked my headphones to see if its a bud. Its not.*

Comment: 1. The otoscope was invented for just such concerns. 2. This isn't a question you should be asking strangers online. Even the competent people of good will can't help you without an exam, and those that fail any or all of the rest of those criteria shouldn't be heeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is to see a doctor. Your primary care doctor is the place to start. He or she can look deep into your ear to see if there is anything lodged in it. It may be a build up of wax, or debris. If so, yoUr doctor can clean it out. If there is nothing blocking your ear drum, and the feeling of blockage continues you should see a specialist. These physicians are called Ear, Nose & Throat (ENT) doctors. They can test to see if there is a problem with how your ear works on the inside. Here is a web site that explains how the ear works.
 It is a remarkable and complex instrument. Protect it. Good luck.

https://www.hearinglink.org/your-hearing/how-the-ear-works/